# Find common elements in a given column from two files and output the column values from each file

Tags: awk, join, comm

I have two files with tab-separated values that look like this:

file1:

```
A    1
B    3
C    1
D    4
```

file2:

```
E    1
B    3
C    2
A    9
```

I would like to find rows between files 1 and 2 where the string in column 1 is the same, then get the corresponding values. The desired output is a single file that looks like this:

```
B    3    3
C    1    2
A    1    9
```

Can this be done with a Unix one-liner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GNU coreutils includes the command `join` that does exactly what you want if line sorting in the result is irrelevant:

`join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

```
A 1 9
B 3 3
C 1 2
```

If you want the tabs back, do:

`join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | tr ' ' '\t'`

```
A   1   9
B   3   3
C   1   2
```

Or use the `t` option to `join`.

(`<()` aka process substitution, requires ksh93 (where the feature originated in), bash or zsh)

Comment: Now the output is sorted alphabetically, instead of according to file2, but it was not clear whether that would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
ire@localhost: sort -k1 file2 | join file1 -
A 1 9
B 3 3
C 1 2
```

If you want tabs in the output, then do

```
sort -k1 file2 | join -t "        " file1 -
```

where you can construct the tab inside the quotes by pressing CTRL-V `<tab>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the output sorted but instead have the same order as file2, awk is a good tool to use:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {val[$1]=$2; next} 
    $1 in val {print $1, val[$1], $2}
' file1 file2
```